# Can I train my classifier multiple times?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, training-data

I am building a basic NLP program using `nltk` and `sklearn`. I have a large dataset in a database and I am wondering what the best way to train the classifier is.

Is it advisable to download the training data in chunks and pass each chunk to the classifier? Is that even possible, or would I be overwriting what was learned from the previous chunk?

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

while True:
    training_set, proceed = download_chunk()  # pseudo
    trained = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB()).train(training_set)
    if not proceed:
        break
```

How is this normally done? I want to avoid keeping the database connection open for too long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you're doing it right now will actually just overwrite the classifier for each chunk in your training data as you're creating a new SklearnClassifier object each time.  What you need to do is instantiate the SklearnClassifier prior to getting into the training loop.  However, looking at the code [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html), it appears that the NLTK SklearnClassifier uses the `fit` method of the underlying Sklearn model.  This means that you can't actually update a model once it is trained.  What you need to do is instantiate the Sklearn model directly and use the `partial_fit` method.  Something like this should work:

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

clf = MultinomialNB() # must instantiate classifier outside of the loop or it will just get overwritten

while True:
    training_set, proceed = download_chunk()  # pseudo
    clf.partial_fit(training_set)
    if not proceed:
        break
```

At the end, you'll have a MultinomialNB() classifier that has been trained on each chunk of your data.

Typically, if the whole dataset will fit in memory, it is somewhat more performant to just download the whole thing and call `fit` once (in which case you could actually use the nltk SklearnClassifier).  See the notes about the `partial_fit` method [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit).  However, if you are unable to fit the entire set in memory, it is certainly common practice to train on chunks of the data.  You can do this by making several calls to the database or by extracting all of the information from the database, placing it in a CSV on your hard drive, and reading chunks of it from there.

### Note

If you're using a shared database with other users, the DBAs may prefer you to extract all of it at once as once as this would (probably) take up fewer DB resources than making several separate, smaller calls to the database would.

Comment: I'll give it a go! Would this "chunk" strategy be okay or is this typically achieved in a different manner? For instance, should I just write a script to download the whole dataset and pass the file into the trainer instead?

Comment: I updated the answer to address your second question.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Just one more thing; the `partial_fit` method takes at least 3 parameters, and reading the docs I am not 100% clear on what they should be. Are you able to explain?

Comment: X is your training data, Y is the outcome variable, and classes is a list of all possible classes that could appear in Y.  This is because, when training on subsets of your data, you may not get every possible class in every subset.  For example, I might have 5 distinct classes `[a, b, c, d, e]` and if I have one chunk of training data that is 5 samples long, I may end up with `[a, a, b, c, a]`.  Classes `d` and `e` aren't in that set of data.  If I don't have the list of possible classes, if `d` or `e` appear in the next training set, my classifier will break (Sklearn will throw an error).

Comment: @Petar The third parameter is only needed for the first call to partial_fit and can be ignored in all subsequent calls.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you.